# Want a clean explanation for GCC preprocessors

Tags: c++, c, gcc, preprocessor

When reading this [document](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html#G_002b_002b-and-GCC), at the end of it, there is one sentence:

> Historically, compilers for many languages, including C++ and Fortran, have been implemented as “preprocessors” which emit another high level language such as C.

Have no idea about preprocessors, any document? Does it mean all these languages will be translated into C source codes?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means (assuming that by "C codes" you mean C source code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would have been better to use  the term  ***source-to-source translator*** instead of "preprocessors" which makes it ambiguous in meaning , but it ain't any wrong to use it either.

Basically , A compiler is a computer program  translates source code from a high-level programming language to a lower level language (e.g., assembly language or machine code).But the document in the question says :

> Historically, compilers for many languages, including C++ and Fortran,
>   have been **implemented** as “**preprocessors**” which emit another high level
>   language such as C.

As per this description , it can be said that earlier , the compilers were **implemented** as *source-to-source translator* . A translator is also a form of preprocessor but its different from the preprocessor used in a program.

> A translator is a computer program that translates a program written
>   in a given programming language into a functionally equivalent program
>   in a different language.

Now, coming to  *preprocessor used in a program* , lets take an example  :

```
#include <stdio.h>// a PREPROCESSOR directive
```

A preprocessor is a program that processes a source file before the
main compilation takes place,( similar to a translator ) **but the difference lies in the fact that HERE it handles directives whose names begin with #**.

Here `#include` is a directive. This directive causes the preprocessor to add the contents of the `stdio.h` file to your
program.This is a typical preprocessor action: adding or replacing text in the source code
before it’s compiled.

Comment: After reading all answers here, now I got two points:

1. preprocessors here means source-to-source translator

2. GCC doesn't use this way today, generates machine codes directly

Comment: @DeanChen yeah !! there you go :)

Comment: Nice! where did you find this detail? link may I have?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks !! Actually only the compiler and translator definition has been taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler" .. everything else is written by me :)

Answer (score 2):

Some languages have been implemented by having the compiler generate C code which is then compiled by the C compiler.  Notable examples include:

- C++ in the earliest days (and C with Classes before that) — `cfront` generated C code from the C++ code.  It ceased to be practical once C++ supported exceptions (read Stroustrup [The Design and Evolution of C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201543303) for more information), but not all C++ compilers used the technique (in fact, I don't know of any other compiler than `cfront` that did it).
- Yacc is compiled to C code.  Bison can be compiled to C or C++ code.
- Lex is compiled to C code. Flex can be compiled to C or C++ code, I believe.
- Informix ESQL/C converts Embedded SQL into pure C.
- Informix 4GL converts I4GL source into ESQL/C, and then uses the ESQL/C compiler to create C code (and the C compiler to create object code and executables), so it has a multi-stage compiler (and I'm simplifying a bit).

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "preprocessor" now has a totally different meaning, and is confusing to be used here. But, yes, here it means some compilers emits its source to another language.

It should be called [source to source compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler). One of the examples is [Cfront](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cfront) (designed by Bjarne Stroustrup himself), which converted C++ to C.

For the normal meaning of the phrase  "preprocessor" in C++, see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/).

Comment: I don't know if it is reasonable to call what Dart does "precompiling"; it implies that Javascript is itself compiled. Of course, most implementations of Javascript compile to some virtual machine or other, and some even have JITs which produce some machine code. Still, it seems like it is stretching the meanings. Also, you've left out the "ce" in "preprocessor", twice.

Comment: @rici Thanks, I deleted the Dart example from the answer, since it's not that relevant to the question(about gcc). Corrected the typo.

Comment: The "preprocessor" described in the document has a different meaning than that you prescribed the link for . It is clearly written that *This sort of preprocessor should not be confused with the C preprocessor, which is an integral feature of the C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++ languages.*

Comment: I think "preprocessor" is used just as a metaphor( I don't know what to call it ) which means other compilers produce another high-level language like C , unlike gcc compilers which produce machine code directly .

Comment: @PHIfounder Maybe I didn't make myself clear enough. That's exactly what I meant. The last link is just for reference not to be confused about the normal meaning of the phrase "preprocessor".

Answer (score -1):

No. Not necessarily.  Many C++ compilers, LIKE THE GCC DOCUMENT SAID, (but not gcc/g++) produce C code output.  Why do they do this?  So they can piggyback on all the backend executable code that C compilers can compile to (X86, AMD, etc.)  By having C as their destination code,they save alot of low end coding on the back end.  Such compilers include the original Cfront and Comeau C/C++.

Comment: g++ certainly does not produce C code output, and neither does clang (compiling C++). I don't believe MS Visual C++ does -- it barely supports C. So what are these *most C++ compilers* of which you speak?

Comment: Cfront did it.  I think g++ used to do it, maybe not anymore.

Comment: You think wrong. And Cfront was only "most C++ compilers" back when it was the only one.

Comment: g++ never did. cfront was a quick proof of concept for c++, long abandoned, and hardly qualifies as "most if not all".

Comment: Comeau C/C++  was/is another one.